# Can we calculate last row of a worksheet in a workbook which we uploaded on webpage in coded classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I have uploaded one excel file to web page , and i am able to get the data on the web page. I have given name to that data range in Excel and use this SQL query "select * from partnumber "in Server side code (classic asp). Partnumber is the name of that range. But i need it to be dynamic. like i need to find the last row of that excel sheet that contain data. Is that Possible ?

```
Set CN= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS1= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

// This will open the excel file
 With CN
     .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source="+DataPath+";" &_
     "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES""" '****hdr=no column
      heading not in 1st row IMEX=1 intermixed  data type
     .Open
    End With  

with RS1
                                  .ActiveConnection=CN
.CursorLocation = 3 
.Cursortype=adOpenDynamic
.LockType = 1
.Source="Select * from partnumber"  // This will get me the data but        
                                           with known row , how can i make 
                                            it dynamic //   
.open
end with
```

Comment: `Select count(*) from partnumber`

Comment: Thanks.. But you have any idea how to write that in classic asp code

Comment: What exactly needs to be dynamic?  Your select query should query all of the data on the sheet, so what's not working for you?

Comment: Well I am trying to upload am excel file on a webpage. Its working and i am getting the data as well.. right i know the data range of that excel file A1 to G20.. But sometimes number of rows may vary. so i need to how to find the last row of that excel file that i have uploaded in server side query using classic asp..basically i am trying to write a excel macro in classic asp in order to find the last row

Comment: If you can run the query you posted, you can also run the one I suggested -  that will give you the number of rows.